# I can't figure out how to Return Values C#

Tags: c#, methods, return, console-application

I'm writing a program using methods and I'm super lost. My assignment is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4aJaGug-OR1WlZhcGdQcHY2Wms/view?usp=sharing) but I can't figure out how to get the values from one method to another.Now I'll clarify a little more, I need the values in the second method to transfer over to the main method and it's not particularly working for me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Ch7Ex3a
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void stuff()
        {

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            double length=0,depth=0,total=compute;

            Console.Write("What is the length in feet? ");
            length=Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("What is the depth in feet? ");
            depth = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("${0}", total);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

         static double compute(double length,double depth)
         {
             double total;
             total = length*depth* 5;
             return total;

         }


    }
}
```

Thank you for your time I know this isn't the best code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: `total=compute` will never compile. Start by reading the MSDN articles on C# Programming as a starting point.

Comment: The assignment requires you to create a new class.  The class should be after the Program class where Main() is located.  The Program Class all methods must be static.  A user generate class the methods don't need to be static.

Comment: Side note: since user can well put, say, `bla-bla-bla` when asked abouut length in feet, `Double.TryParse` is a better solution than `Convert.ToDouble`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is this add this line after reading both lenght and depth values:

```
double total = compute(length, depth);
```

You're telling that `total` will be what `return` from method compute.

Remember to send the parameters to method, and always call the method after you read both values, otherwise they'll be zero when the method is called. You code should look like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double length = 0, depth = 0;

    Console.Write("What is the length in feet? ");
    length = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Write("What is the depth in feet? ");
    depth = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    double total = compute(length, depth);

    Console.WriteLine("${0}", total);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just call the method:

```
Console.WriteLine("${0}", compute(length,depth));
```

Or:

```
double length = 0, depth = 0, total = 0;
total = compute(length, depth);
```

Then:

```
Console.WriteLine("${0}", total);
```

Or in c#6:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{total}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You call a method with parameters like this:

```
var length = 4;  // example values
var depth = 8;   // example values

var toal = compute(length, depth);
```

After this your variable `total` will have the value `160`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly print the result to the console by using

```
Console.WriteLine("${0}", compute(length,depth));
```

By doing like this you need not be declare an additional variable `total` So the declaration Will be like the following,

```
   double length=0,depth=0;
```